# How to obtain the max % drawdown in the List of Trades?

Tags: metadata, pine-script, percentage

[image]

In a Strategy,
in LIST OF TRADES,
I want to obtain the max % of the drawdown column.

This is not the Max Drawdown of the Overview.

Sadly, PERFORMANCE SUMMARY does not offer this number.

Please ?

Answer (score 1):

try this out bro

```
strategy_closedtrades_max_drawdown_percent(trade_num) =>
    endP = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(trade_num) * math.abs(strategy.closedtrades.size(trade_num))
    prof = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(trade_num)
    result = prof / endP *100

lastDrawDown = strategy_closedtrades_max_drawdown_percent(strategy.closedtrades-1)
```

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading